# Python script doesn't change mouse position in games

Tags: python, position, cursor, pynput

so I'm trying to make a Python script that jitters the mouse position, now it works about anywhere apart from games, I've tried cs:go and cod, but no results, in menus where the cursor shows it does actually jitter the cursor, but I don't know why it doesn't change the crosshair position as well.

```
import time
import threading
from pynput import keyboard, mouse

jitter_active = False

def jitter_mouse():
    global jitter_active
    toggle = False
    start_pos = None

    while jitter_active:
        if not toggle:
            # move the mouse to the right
            mouse_controller.move(10, 0)
        else:
            # move the mouse to the left
            mouse_controller.move(-10, 0)

        toggle = not toggle
        time.sleep(0.01)

def on_press(key):
    global jitter_active
    if key == keyboard.Key.f12:
        return False
    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('x'):
        jitter_active = not jitter_active
        if jitter_active:
            threading.Thread(target=jitter_mouse).start()

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.f12:
        return False

mouse_controller = mouse.Controller()

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

expectation:
for the script to change the in-game crosshair position